# How to filter special characters but not all special characters?

Tags: php

I want to filter special character but not all special characters
so my code is correct?

```
if (!ctype_alnum($skypename)) {
echo 'Invalid skype name.';
exit;
}

This is valid
echo123
echo.123
echo-123

This is invalid
echo@123
echo*123
```

How i can filter all special characters but not . or -
Thanks you

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Rizier123 Sorry, i have added question last few mins i forgot about it.

Comment: And what is the definition of: `special characters` ? Or in other words: You only want names which only contains: [a-zA-Z0-9][.] ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I want filter all special characters but not "." and "-" which this is valid echo.123 echo-123 and other is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:

(If `$skypename` only is allowed to contain: `[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]`)

```
<?php

    $skypename = "test@sdf";  //As an example

    if(!preg_match_all("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+$/", $skypename, $matches))
        echo "not ";
    echo "valid";

?>
```